# MYSQL - Trigger - Update field and add the data to another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

Happy Holidays  :D , i got a little project on process and would like to ask some questions:

I have a DB called TEST

I have a table called "CUSTOMER" has these fields:

```
id, name , last_name, status (YES, NO).
```

I have another table called "ACTIVE CUSTOMERS" has these fields:

```
id, customer_id, name, last_name, documentation.
```

The question is, can I create a trigger for when UPDATE with the value `YES` on field `status` of `CUSTOMER` table automatically customer data (id, name) add in the table `CUSTOMER_ACTIVE`? 
And the second question would be How is the trigger syntax?

Comment: usually there is no reason to move records because one is active or inactive. do you really need this? customers may have some relations as well. whats then?

Comment: Yes, its necesary because the table CUSTOMER_ACTIVATION has another fields as documentation and the CUSTOMER table doesnt have.

Comment: Still that doesn't make much sense. Wouldn't recommend to this like you want to either. Anyway, you can look up the trigger syntax in the manual and have a try before asking here. This is no code factory here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean something like this?

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `set_status` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `customer` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF new.status = 'YES' 
THEN 
    INSERT INTO active_customers (id, name) VALUES (new.id , new.name);
END IF;
END
```